# Backbone error if I have more than 1 JSON group

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm currently playing around with Backbone.js and have ran into an issue in dealing with JSON and outputting it.

The problem I'm have is that my code runs just fine if I have only one entry in my JSON file. However if I add a second, or more, the code fires the error function.

I've tried checking my JSON format and it returns valid. Here is the code:

```
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: null,
        img: null,
        slug: null,
        excerpt: null,
        type: null
    },
});

var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend ({
    model: Post,
    url: "/json/postCollection.json",
    parse: function(resp, xhr) {
        console.log(resp)
        return resp;
    }
});

allPosts = new Posts();

PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.status = new Posts( null, { view: this });
        this.status.bind("reset", this.render);
        this.getPosts();
    },
    getPosts: function() {
        this.render(this.status.fetch({ 
            success: function(data){
                return(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log('Failed to load postCollection');
            }
        }));
    },
    render: function() {
        var el = $('.posts');
        this.status.each( function(model) {
            var postTemplate = model.get('type')+"Template";

            var variables = { 
                title: model.get('title'), 
                img: model.get('img'), 
                type: model.get('type'),
                excerpt: model.get('excerpt'),
                slug: model.get('slug') 
            };

            console.log(variables);

            var template = _.template( $("#"+postTemplate).html(), variables );

            el.append( template );
        });
    }
});

var post_view = new PostView();
```

And my JSON: (again if I have only one entry, the above JS works)

```
[
    {
        "title": "Entry Title 1",
        "img": "image.gif",
        "slug": "entry-1",
        "excerpt": "lorem",
        "type": "casestudy"
    },
    {
        "title": "Entry Title 1",
        "img": "image.gif",
        "slug": "entry-1",
        "excerpt": "lorem",
        "type": "casestudy"
    }
]
```

EDIT (RESOLVED):

Thank you dbaseman!

You pointed me in the right direction to find the issue. I'm using a vagrant setup, and the caseproof-lamp box. Default configuration doesn't have JSON mime type set.

The solution was to SSH into the box, and add the following line to my /etc/mime.types:

`application/json json`

Before the JSON file was being transferred as plain text. For anyone having similar issues if you want to check the mime-type in javascript use:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', "/json/postCollection.json", false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

Comment: Are you getting any other errors in the console? I copied your code almost exactly and it works fine for me...

Comment: I get the response from this line console.log('Failed to load postCollection'); - if I try to add variables to the error function it only shows me an empty object, but can't see any error messages in the object. Edit: sorry the error is not exactly empty, it returns this format: d {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, _events: Object}
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_events: Object
length: 0
models: Array[0]
__proto__: f

Comment: You might want to add the server response to your question, as that's likely where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you dbaseman! You pointed me in the right direction to find the issue. I'm using a vagrant setup, and the caseproof-lamp box. Default configuration doesn't have JSON mime type set.

The solution was to SSH into the box, and add the following line to my /etc/mime.types:

    application/json json

Comment: Scratch that, I am now sending the right mime-type. It is working with up to 2 entries in my JSON, but if I add a 3rd my error function is fired again with the same results I described above.

Comment: If your question is resolved, you can always post an answer to it and accept it.  This way, we'll all know that your question was answered.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is async so you when you call return the getPosts callback its returning the data from that closure not your outer function. You need to nest your render call like this.

```
 PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this, "render");
         this.status = new Posts( null, { view: this });
         this.status.bind("reset", this.render);
         this.getPosts();
    },
    getPosts: function() {
         var self = this;
         this.status.fetch({ 
             success: function(data){
                 self.render(data);
             },
             error: function(){
                 console.log('Failed to load postCollection');
             }
         }));
    },
    render: function() {
         var el = $('.posts');
         this.status.each( function(model) {
         var postTemplate = model.get('type')+"Template";

         var variables = { 
            title: model.get('title'), 
            img: model.get('img'), 
            type: model.get('type'),
            excerpt: model.get('excerpt'),
            slug: model.get('slug') 
         };

        console.log(variables);

        var template = _.template( $("#"+postTemplate).html(), variables );

        el.append( template );
    });
}
});
```